# I have a very high $R^2 (0.96)$ for my ARDL time series model, is this problematic?

Tags: r, time-series, goodness-of-fit, r-squared, ardl

All my variables are stationary, so cointigration can't be the problem. I have included one lag of the dependent variable and 5 explanatory variables. When I remove the explanatory variables, the R^2 doesnt change very much, only when I exclude the lag of the dependent variable, the R^2 is drastically reduced. I also checked the residuals and they dont seem to violate any assumptions.

```
Residual standard error: 0.005334 on 157 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.968, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9664 
F-statistic:   594 on 8 and 157 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: If your dependent variable is highly autocorrelated (close to having a unit root), this is to be expected.

Comment: @RichardHardy I use Newey-West std. errors to get rid of the autocorrelation. Do you have any suggestions on how to further proceed? Is this problematic or rather irrelevant, as long as all required assumptions are met?

Comment: Robust standard errors address autocorrelation in errors, not in variables. You do not need them if your errors are not autocorrelated. Regarding the main question, I do not see a high $R^2$ value as a problem.